# Azure Application Insights not tracking SQL Queries

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

We can no longer see the actual SQL queries being executed in Application Insights after we had upgraded our web apps to .Net Core 3.1. We left the EF Core at version 2.2 due to some serious performance issues with EF Core 3.x, so not sure if that has anything to do with that? All we see now is just the target DB details:

[image]

Prior to that we were on AspNetCore 2.2 with EF Core 2.2 and everything was working fine, Application Insights was showing us the actual SQL statements being executed.

We've tried the suggestions form Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query), which suggested to add the **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** nuget package to the project, but that did absolutely nothing.

We've also tried turning on the "***Application Insights -> Sql Commands***" option in our App Service, but that did nothing either.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working again?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Nuget packages we are referencing:

[image]

Comment: Does it work locally? and also please share us the .csproj file to see which packages you're using.

Comment: No, it doesn't work locally either.

Comment: please share us the .csproj file to see which packages you're using.

Comment: Done. Edited the post

Comment: But I cannot see `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` nuget package.

Comment: This is the reverted version of the project, but we did try adding the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nuget package and it did nothing for us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is because SQL command collection is **off by default** from version 2.14 onwards. It can be enabled with:

```
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module. EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });
```

More information here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/28

Answer (score 5):

It seems that it's an issue about the latest version of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.14.0`. I can repro the issue in **2.14.0**, but it works when I downgrade it to **2.12.0**.

The test result with using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.12.0`:

[image]

Comment: Simply magical! Thanks Ivan! I've tried it with ver. 2.12.2 and it worked. I didn't even have to add the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` nuget package.

We'll just have to wait until they fix up this issue in the later versions.