# Application Insights not logging SQL Dependencies queries

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, .net-5

I'm using an App service hosted in Azure using Asp.Net Core & .Net5. I turned on SQL dependency tracking using below settings in appSettings.config. But I see SQL dependencies logged without SQL command Text. Is there any other settings to enable to see SQL commands in the log?

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "my guid key",
    "EnableDependencyTracking": true,
    "DependencyTrackingOptions": {
      "EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
    },
    "sampling": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 5
    }
  },
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036448/azure-application-insights-not-tracking-sql-queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your settings in `appSettings.config` is for `Azure Function`, not `ASP.NET Core applications`.

For ASP.NET Core applications, It is now required to opt-in to SQL Text collection by using

```
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module. EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });
```

**For more details, you can refer official doc**

[Advanced SQL tracking to get full SQL Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query)